# how to index two mongodb collections in one Elasticsearch index

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

I have two mongodb collections, `Transactions` and `Users`,this is transaction example

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5cdd391e1e4b8f0cb8e17d0f"), "txId" :      
"6910dc01ff167d90e8fe249ce68a5149f82d099345473fab02916068570974bd",  
"sender" : ObjectId("5cdbe473ca52557874005809"), "receiver" :  
 ObjectId("5cdd26a6b2d370061e8435d7"), "senderWalletId" :  
 ObjectId("5cdbe473ca5255787400580a"), "receiverWalletId" : 
 ObjectId("5cdd26a6b2d370061e8435d8"), "status" : "success", "type" : 
 "transfer", "amount" : 3000, "totalFee" : 40, "createdAt" : 
 ISODate("2019-05-16T10:19:10.809Z"), "updatedAt" : 
 ISODate("2019-05-16T10:19:10.809Z"), "__v" : 0 }
```

and this is a users example

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d010a140f0c30757f59fe18"), "role" : "client",  
"status" : "active", "isPhoneVerified" : true, "personalDocuments" : [ 
], "email" : "example.com", "firstName" : "mm", "lastName" : "mm", 
"phoneNumber" : "0000000", "password" : "$2a$10$.", "pushToken" : 
"cSRdsgJXAc67k-PIKwHvslINb0kAaStVzmYPqeIH5oudVTqppHFjxbGEg2B-
 1Xe8P0iTH0EYB9PHbKKey", "created_at" : 
 ISODate("2019-06-12T14:20:04.338Z"), "updated_at" : 
 ISODate("2019-06-17T13:33:41.613Z"), "__v" : 0, "verifyPhoneCode" : 
 null }
```

i've indexed the Transactions documents in ES using logstash and the mongodb-input-plugin successfully, this is the mapping generated by ES for that

```
 "puretransactionsmodified" : {
 "mappings" : {
  "doc" : {
    "properties" : {
      "@timestamp" : {
        "type" : "date"
      },
      "@version" : {
        "type" : "text",
        "fields" : {
          "keyword" : {
            "type" : "keyword",
            "ignore_above" : 256
          }
        }
      },
      "__v" : {
        "type" : "long"
      },
      "amount" : {
        "type" : "long"
      },
      "createdAt" : {
        "type" : "date"
      },
      "host" : {
        "type" : "text",
        "fields" : {
          "keyword" : {
            "type" : "keyword",
            "ignore_above" : 256
          }
        }
      },
      "id" : {
        "type" : "text",
        "fields" : {
          "keyword" : {
            "type" : "keyword",
            "ignore_above" : 256
          }
        }
      },
      "log_entry" : {
        "type" : "text",
        "fields" : {
          "keyword" : {
            "type" : "keyword",
            "ignore_above" : 256
          }
        }
      },
      "logdate" : {
        "type" : "date"
      },
      "mongo_id" : {
        "type" : "text",
        "fields" : {
          "keyword" : {
            "type" : "keyword",
            "ignore_above" : 256
          }
        }
      },
      "receiver" : {
        "type" : "text",
        "fields" : {
          "keyword" : {
            "type" : "keyword",
            "ignore_above" : 256
          }
        }
      },
      "receiverWalletId" : {
        "type" : "text",
        "fields" : {
          "keyword" : {
            "type" : "keyword",
            "ignore_above" : 256
          }
        }
      },
      "sender" : {
        "type" : "text",
        "fields" : {
          "keyword" : {
            "type" : "keyword",
            "ignore_above" : 256
          }
        }
      },
      "senderWalletId" : {
        "type" : "text",
        "fields" : {
          "keyword" : {
            "type" : "keyword",
            "ignore_above" : 256
          }
        }
      },
      "status" : {
        "type" : "text",
        "fields" : {
          "keyword" : {
            "type" : "keyword",
            "ignore_above" : 256
          }
        }
      },
      "total" : {
        "type" : "long"
      },
      "totalFee" : {
        "type" : "long"
      },
      "txId" : {
        "type" : "text",
        "fields" : {
          "keyword" : {
            "type" : "keyword",
            "ignore_above" : 256
          }
        }
      },
      "type" : {
        "type" : "text",
        "fields" : {
          "keyword" : {
            "type" : "keyword",
            "ignore_above" : 256
          }
        }
      },
      "updatedAt" : {
        "type" : "date"
      }
    }
    }
   }
  }
 }
```

when i've tried to index both the collections for some analysis using that same plugin

```
 input {
    mongodb {
            uri => 'mongodb://**.**.**.***:27017/db'
            placeholder_db_dir => '/home/jhon/Desktop 
            /userstransactions'
            placeholder_db_name => 'logstash_sqlite.db'
            collection => 'transactions'
            batch_size => 202
            parse_method => "simple"
            }
     mongodb {
            uri => 'mongodb://**.**.**.***:27017/db'
            placeholder_db_dir => '/home/jhon/Desktop
            /userstransactions'
            placeholder_db_name => 'logstash_sqlite.db'
            collection => 'wallets'
            batch_size => 202
            parse_method => "simple"
            }
  }
```

it did not work all i had was the transactions , i want to have under the `reciever` and the `sender` fields in `transaction` the `name` of the reciever provided by `user`, i'm a newbie on this i've also tried mapping it myself but did not work.